# kendo ui dropdownlist posts array

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

im using dropdownlists in my kendogrid popup forms. im using them in  template like

```
 <label for="primaryClient" style="text-align:left">Primary Account*</label>
  <div class="k-edit-field"><input name="primaryClient" data-bind="value:primaryClient" data-value-field="value" data-text-field="text" data-source="dsDocClientGroup" data-role="dropdownlist" required validationMessage="Required" /></div>
```

However when i check whats actually being posted. its posting an array:

primaryClient['label'], 
primaryClient['value']

any ideas while this would be happening

Comment: post your `save` method code so we can help you.

Comment: THanks Jaimin Ive reposted the question as a full example if you could have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26767820/kendo-ui-drop-downs-posting-arrays